# Listview Highlight move when scrolling

Tags: android, listview

this is the activity

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v,int position, long id) {
        String str;

        if (nRowSelected>=0) {
            View row=parent.getChildAt(nRowSelected);
            if (row!=null) {
                row.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            }
        }
        nRowSelected=position;

        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    }//onListItemClick
```

this is my listview

```
        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="425dp" 
            >
        </ListView>
```

i need highlight single choice. i choose/focus row number 1. but when i scroll, the focus is more than one. the row focus in row 8 too

this is the capture

[image: Image 1]

and

[image: Image2]

how to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

You are fighting the way Adapter's recycle the row layouts... You need to extend your current Adapter and override `getView()` to highlight the correct row (and only the correct row).

At the most basic level it would look like:

```
public View getView(...) {
    View view = super.getView(...);

    if(position == mRowSelected) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    }
    else { // You must use a default case to "un-highlight" the reused layout
        view.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: error in this line  `View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);` `The method getView(int, View, ViewGroup) is undefined for the type ListActivity` @Sam

Comment: You must extend an Adapter, like ArrayAdapter, to use `getView()`. What type of Adapter are you using?

Comment: Why use 0xFFFFFFFF instead Color.TRANSPARENT?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the xml:

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

Comment: Why not use @android:color/transparent instead #00000000?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `xml` code with following::

```
<ListView
   android:id="@android:id/list"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="425dp" 
   android:cacheColorHint="#00000000">
</ListView>
```

Comment: Why not use @android:color/transparent instead #00000000?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please see the below code might be help it is single choice selection example follow this it work good .

```
public class List17 extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Use the built-in layout for showing a list item with a single
    // line of text whose background is changes when activated.
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, mStrings));
    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    // Tell the list view to show one checked/activated item at a time.
    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    // Start with first item activated.
    // Make the newly clicked item the currently selected one.
    getListView().setItemChecked(0, true);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Make the newly clicked item the currently selected one.
    getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
}

private String[] mStrings = Cheeses.sCheeseStrings;
```

}

This is list activity it does't matter that you have list view or list activity.